# AWS Lambda - Unable to connect to SQL Server RDS

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-api-gateway

Hi I was having the same problem as **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949940/aws-lambda-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-rds-in-vpc/43960690#43960690)** but the posted answer (no sample code) wasn't provided so I will start a new thread and ask you guys.

I have created a ***AWS Serverless Application (.Net Core)*** project for our lambda function and below code is what I used to connect in AWS RDS.

---

```
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=rds4abc1190.asdfqwerqb9l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,2855;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=mypassword;Encrypt=False";

using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
     using (var Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Customer", Conn))
     {
          Conn.Open(); //<-- this is where the error fires.

          SqlDataReader rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
                myDbItems.Add(rdr[1].ToString());
          }

          Conn.Close();
      }
 }
```

---

Using the above code works fine when running on local machine but if deployed in AWS Api Gateway, that code would error.

> "errorType": "SqlException", "errorMessage": "Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=781; handshake=1957; [Login] initialization=40; authentication=122; [Post-Login] complete=12219;",

Comment: Is you lambda resides inside a VPC subnet that is in the same VPC as the SQLServer having access to the SQLServer RDS subnet?

Answer (score 1):

Added the following in each function in the serverless.template.

```
"Role": "arn:aws:iam::053984854873:role/1234-Dev",              
    "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole", "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-ABC1234","LambdaAccess-1234" ], 
    "VpcConfig" : {
        "SecurityGroupIds" : ["sg-4f2cbff1","sg-3584a444"],
        "SubnetIds" : ["subnet-f2520727","subnet-388b4ab2"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is the same as the referenced post, then there wasn't any sample code because it isn't a code issue.  He upgraded the database engine version in RDS because the drivers that AWS Lambda uses wouldn't support connections to MSSQL 2008 R2, while his local machine had the necessary drivers.

Here is the AWS doc on upgrading RDS SQL Server Engine versions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.SQLServer.html

Comment: We resolved my issue. We just added/incuded the VpcConfig, Roles, and Policies in the serverless.template.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Making sure the Lambda functions are running in the correct VPC with the correct roles and security groups can be a sticking point.  I would set up the policies on the role in the IAM console, for what it's worth, so you don't have to input the policies on every serverless template you write.